# Android SQLiteOpenHelper - different class for every table?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I was reading this article (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) to learn about SQLite databases in android apps.

In the article he has a tip:

> It is good practice to create a separate class per table. This class defines static onCreate() and onUpgrade() methods. These methods are called in the corresponding methods of SQLiteOpenHelper. This way your implementation of SQLiteOpenHelper stays readable, even if you have several tables.

if I understand this tip correctly I should have a class for each table that I have in my database?

Is that really the best practice?

If so, what about complex queries that uses multiple tables? how do I manage that if the creation is in different classes?

How do I correctly keep the database version? for each table change I will change the database version number?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SQLiteOpenHelper` manages database files, not tables. You manage the tables yourself with the given database lifecycle callbacks (`onCreate()`, `onUpgrade()`).

Quickly reading one could interpret that the author advocates creating a separate database helper for each table (I did at first), but that's not the case. That would have been bad advice.

To reiterate the author's intent:

- One database helper class.
- The helper involves separate table-specific helper classes which are not `SQLiteOpenHelper`s but just doing part of the work for the top-level database helper.

Comment: Thanks. Is it better to create the tables with queries on the onCreate method or have a database ready in the assets folder and copy it?

Comment: Imagine a database with 100 tables. Managing all of the creation and upgrade logic in a single class would result in a very long class with very long `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` methods. Lars Vogel is recommending breaking that up, using separate classes per table to hold the create and upgrade logic. You still have only one `SQLiteOpenHelper`, and its `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` would delegate their work to static methods on the other classes.

Comment: "To reliably have one helper per table would also mean having separate database files, complicating thigs unnecessarily" -- that is not what Mr. Vogel is advising.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, reread the quoted part with additional context from the linked tutorial and rephrased the answer.

Comment: @CommonsWare : To be fair the wording of the 'tip' is slightly ambiguous especially at that stage of the tutorial. It isn't until reading further that it becomes obvious "this class" (as it's referred to in the 'tip') is in fact simply a POJO.

Comment: @Squonk: Well, I never claimed it was Lars' *best* post... :-)

Comment: but all the creation and upgrading of the database is still in the helper class - which will make it a very long class, right?

Comment: Not really, the long code parts can be pulled to the table-specific classes and the helper contains only row or two to invoke them.

Comment: I don't see in the articles example how this is done. can you please help me out to figure it out? would like my app to be built properly :)